# Back button always triggers previous activity's onCreate() unless launchMode is singleTop

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

The [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) states the following:

> [image]
>
> **Figure 1.** A representation of how each new activity in a task adds an item to the **back** stack. When the user presses the Back button, the current activity is destroyed and the previous activity resumes.

However, whenever I start at Activity A, use an intent to open Activity B, then press the back button to go back to A, A's `onCreate()` method is always called, rather than it simply getting resumed.

Adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the Android manifest for Activity A (my launch activity) no longer causes this triggering of `onCreate()`. I.e, the previous activity does indeed just resume, rather than getting destroyed and recreated.

Why is this the case? I find it odd that the documentation appears to explain things under the assumption that its "Activity 2"'s launch mode is not set to the default of `standard`.

Edit:

I've created a new app to test things out. Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="...">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".OtherActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the order in which my lifecycle methods got logged:

```
//activity bar back button
MainActivity onCreate
MainActivity onStart
MainActivity onResume
MainActivity startActivity(intent)
MainActivity onPause
OtherActivity onCreate
OtherActivity onStart
OtherActivity onResume
MainActivity onStop
//<press button here>
OtherActivity onPause
MainActivity onDestroy
MainActivity onCreate
MainActivity onStart
MainActivity onResume
OtherActivity onStop
OtherActivity onDestroy

//AOS back button
MainActivity onCreate
MainActivity onStart
MainActivity onResume
MainActivity startActivity(intent)
MainActivity onPause
OtherActivity onCreate
OtherActivity onStart
OtherActivity onResume
MainActivity onStop
OtherActivity onBackPressed //press button here
OtherActivity onPause
MainActivity onStart
MainActivity onResume
OtherActivity onStop
OtherActivity onDestroy
```

Here is the code that starts OtherActivity:

```
buttonStartActivity.setOnClickListener {
    Log.d(LOGCAT_TAG, "MainActivity startActivity(intent)")
    var intent: Intent = Intent(this, OtherActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: This seems unusual, does this reproduce in a minimal example app?  Also just to confirm: you don't, by any chance, have the "don't keep activities" developer option enabled, correct?

Comment: this is quite consistent behavior as mentioned in documentation. I suggest you try any public sample app e.g. https://github.com/android/architecture-samples and compare with your implementation.

Comment: @RyanMentley no, I don't have that option enabled, and I don't think it would cause such behaviour (I'm not closing the app for this). My app doesn't do much, it's essentially a `ListView` hooked up to a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: @BirenderSingh hmm, that response contradicts the previous comment, so I'm puzzled. But that aside, if the behaviour is expected, then why does the official documentation seem to explain things in a way that assumes the activities' launch modes are not the default of `standard`? It goes on like that from the start, and never even mentions singleTop till it reaches the topic of launch modes much later on.

Comment: hi @Cloud, i'm sorry if my comment wasn't clear. What i meant was that documentation is correct and consistent with my past experiences (verified it couple of times). I think u're missing something, can't comment without lookign at the code. I suggest u look at a sample (public) project from google and compare with urs.

Comment: Please post your manifest and the code you use to start `ActivityB`. The behaviour you are describing is not the standard default behaviour, so you are doing something strange. Also, please add logging to the lifecycle methods of `ActivityA` (`onStart, onStop, onCreate, onDestroy, onPause, onResume`) and indicate if the first instance of `ActvityA` is being destroyed after `ActivityB` is started or after you press the BACK button in `ActivityB` to go back to `ActivityA`.

Comment: Ah, now I understand, @BirenderSingh. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @DavidWasser I have edited my question with that information. I have done tests with both the activity bar back button (I've always been using that) and with the AOE back button, and it seems the behaviour I'm describing only happens with the activity bar back button.